# How to (re-) arrange this python code without breaking sqlalchemy relevant dependencies?

Tags: python, reflection, sqlalchemy, primary-key, command-line-arguments

I have a little problem regarding "arranging of code, which depends on each other" when setting an sqlalchemy mapping to a sqlite database in python.

The goal is to write a script, whcih satisfies the following conditions:

1. Gets a `filename` parameter as command line argument.
2. Based on the `filename` it should create an absolute path to the SQLite database.
3. It should connect to the database and create an `engine`
4. It shall reflect the tables in this databases.
5. It should `monkey patch` the column `id` in the table `mytable` as a primary key column, since the table doesn't habe a primary key and sqlalchemy requires one.

So I came up with this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base  

def create_path(file_name):
    # generate absolute path to file_name

path_to_file = create_path("my_file_name.sqlite")
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///{path}'.format(path=path_to_file), echo=False)
Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True) # Monkey patching the id column as primary key.

def main(argv):
    # parse file_name here from argv
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    for row in session.query(MyTable).all():
        print row
    return "Stop!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

But this is a doomed construction and I don't see how I could rearrange my code without breaking the dependencies.

1. To be able to create `MyClass` I need `Base` to be defined before `MyClass`.
2. To be able to create `Base` I need `engine` to be defined before `Base`.
3. To be able to create `engine` I need `path_to_file` to be defined before `engine`.
4. To be able to create `path_to_file` outside of `main()` I need `create_file()` to be defined before `path_to_file`.
5. And so on...

Hopefully you see where I am stuck...

Any suggestions?

*Edit:* By the way, the code works, but only with a hardcoded filename in the top of the script.

Comment: `Base` is just an instance of `declarative_base`. Why not just subclass `declarative_base`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see why you could not use the `declarative` mapping still complety. I think the key to the proper dependencies is to know what to put in the module and what in the script/function. With python, you can easily define the class inside the `run_script` function.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

def create_path(filename):
    import os
    fn = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'sqlite_files', filename))
    return fn

def run_script(filename):
    path_to_file = create_path(filename)

    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///{path}'.format(path=path_to_file), echo=True)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)

    # object model
    class MyTable(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'my_table'
        __table_args__ = {'autoload': True}
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True) # Monkey patching the id column as primary key

    # script itself
    session = Session()
    for row in session.query(MyTable).all():
        print row
    return "Stop!"

def main(argv):
    assert argv, "must specify a database file name"
    run_script(argv[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem using the classical mapping approach of SQLAlchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, mapper

class MyTable(object):    
    pass    

def main():
    path_to_file = create_path("my_file_name.sqlite")
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///{path}'.format(path=path_to_file), echo=False)

    metadata = MetaData()
    metadata.bind = engine
    my_table = Table('mytable',
                     metadata,
                     Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True), # Monkey patching the id column as primary key.
                     autoload=True,
                     autoload_with=engine)
    mapper(MyTable, my_table)

    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    # Do Stuff!
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the capability to do any testing at my current location. But I suggest moving all of that code to `main()` as follows. Also, `MyTable` subclasses `declarative_base`.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer 
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base    

class MyTable(declarative_base):     
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'     
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True}      

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True) # Monkey patching the id column as primary key.  

def create_path(file_name):     
    # generate absolute path to file_name  


def main(argv):     # parse file_name here from argv   
    path_to_file = create_path("my_file_name.sqlite") 
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///{path}'.format(path=path_to_file), echo=False) 
    Base = MyTable()
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)  

    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)     
    session = Session()     
    for row in session.query(MyTable).all():         
        print row     
    return "Stop!"  

if __name__ == '__main__':     
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this results in `sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: No engine is bound to this Table's MetaData. Pass an engine to the Table via autoload_with=<someengine>, or associate the MetaData with an engine via metadata.bind=<someengine>`

Comment: 1) which line is this error generated at?  2) maybe you could avoid creating `class MyTable` entirely and do `Base.__tablename__ = "my_table"` and so on inside the body of `main()`

Comment: I found a different solution for my problem. Posted it as an answer. Thank you very much for your time and effort. :-)